# .NET Application Settings -> setting the null string

Tags: .net, string, null, settings

What should I type (in both cases) in my app.config's applicationSettings section so that, when I read Settings, I can get the following:

1. Settings.Default.FooString == null
2. Settings.Default.FooString == string.Empty

?
I guess there is no way to achieve both situations, or am I missing something?

Diffrerenciating whether string value is null or empty is unfortunately required, because this value goes to different system, that takes diffrent decisions upon these two.
thanks

---

further info:

Settings.Designer.cs is being regenerated each time you modify the settings tab.
The sample generated setting is:

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
    public string Foo {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["Foo "]));
        }
        set {
            this["Foo "] = value;
        }
    }
```

the problem is with generated [DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]. It works as I want when I correct it by hand with [DefaultSettingValueAttribute(null)], however, I would need to do this after whenever I modify any thing on the settings tab, which is unacceptable.

any clues?

Answer (score 4):

For a `null`, you simply omit the whole `<value />` element.

For a `string.Empty` you use `<value />` or `<value></value>`.

Comment: same answer as above, you do not have any <add /> elements in applicationsettings

Comment: @Łukasz Podolak - I guess both @matt-dot-net and I thought you meant the `appSettings` element. Answer updated.

Comment: if you omit the <value> element you get  System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Required attribute 'value' not found.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, there is no way to achieve both situations, because `null != String.Empty`.

But you could use `Boolean String.IsNullOrEmpty(String)` to check for both situations.

Answer (score 2):

leave the appSetting undefined if you want null, use value="" if you want String.Empty

Comment: It isn't realted with <appSettings>, It is <applicationSettings>

Comment: sorry... i think it's the same principle though.